# How does this site compute "consecutive" days visited?

Tags: support

I have visited this site every day for quite a while.  For some reason, seemingly at random, the 'consecutive days visited' counter seems to reset.  I looked at it yesterday and it was up to 8 or 9, and then today it is back down to 2.

Does it re-set if I don't visit in a 24-hour period?  If so, I think that is an unusual definition of 'consecutive days'.  If I visit at 8 a.m. Sunday morning, then again at 4 p.m. Monday afternoon, I think most folk would consider that 2 consecutive days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeff explained, they use UTC-time, but he didn't tell you, that UTC-time is always shown at the top of the page, when you hover over your name, at the bottom of the pop up.

And!

And visiting isn't always what you think it is! It happened to me too. You visit, and visit, but you have to enter the question section. Watching your beautiful profile isn't enough.

And!

Since all pages here work in the same way (think so), you should ask such questions at SE->Meta which is also known as Meta (pure Meta). Where you shouldn't ask this question, but find the answer, because it has already been asked.

Comment: I think your second paragraph explains my problem.  I come to the site, scan the page which has 'top questions', but if none are interesting to me, I just leave.  I guess that doesn't count as a visit.  Also, I apologize for asking in the skeptics->meta and not the SE meta...didn't even think of that.

Comment: @fred: Don't apologize, about 50% of the questions in special meta-sections could be asked on the central meta. Here, on skeptics, less so. For other themes, more so.

Comment: And I guess 'top question' already counts as visit, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Our day is a 24 hour UTC period beginning at 00:00:00 UTC and ending 23:59:59 UTC.

Comment: I was up to 60+ consecutive days at one point when my counter was reset due to a seemingly arbitrary designation of a day.  I could conceivably visit at 23:59 UTC on one day, then return 24 hours and 3 minutes later, and my counter would reset.  I am annoyed...